# How Can I get the browser window size without the address bar Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating some tests using selenium java, I want to get the entire window size(The size of the browser without the address bar)

I tried to use driver().manage().window().getSize() but this one gets the height of the window including the address bar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getSize()` on the `html` tag

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

```
private static Long getHeight(JavascriptExecutor driver) {
    return (Long) (driver.executeScript("return window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight"));
}

private static Long getWidth(JavascriptExecutor driver) {
    return (Long) (driver.executeScript("return window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth"));
}
```